# android studio button Click recognition

Tags: android, android-studio

The problem is, that when this button is pressed nothing happens. any Ideas?

```
btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.IbuttonStart);
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            handler.post(timeCounter);
            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            btnRestart.setEnabled(false);
            btnLap.setEnabled(true);
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

Comment: Please post your whole class again. The xml also sometimes help.

Comment: This is also not and Android-Studio specific problem, so you might edit your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your edits I can see that `btnStart.setOnClickListener` is called twice, so the first listener gets replaced.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look in the edits. You are a life saver <3.